# Cant store validation metrics when using imagedatagenerator as Keras model input

Tags: python, validation, keras, imagedatagenerator

I wanted to display a graph of the training and validation accuracy of my keras model using the history log. I cant generate the log while using imagedatagenerator input. It only works for input in the form of numpy arrays but that is too slow.

**Typically this works:
**

```
from datetime import datetime
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

es = EarlyStopping( monitor='val_loss', patience = 5, verbose=1, mode=min)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='breast not breast/mymodel--{epoch:02d}.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max',verbose=2, save_best_only=True)
callbacks = [checkpoint,es]


history = model.fit(x, y,validation_split = 0.05, epochs=1, batch_size=32, callbacks=callbacks,
                   verbose=2, shuffle=True)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

**However, but using numpy arrays x and y is wayyy too slow
**
Hence, I provide input via imagedatagenerator. However, this sort of input is incompatible with the validation_split parameter in model.fit. Hence, my model.fit looks like this:

```
model_history=model.fit(train_set, 
                        validation_split=0.05,validation_data=test_set,  
                        epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=5,  
                        validation_steps=10,
                        callbacks=callbacks ,verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

But this does not log or display the validation metrics. I just get one value for each validation metric but an array of values for each training metric. e.g.

```
print(model_history.history['accuracy'])
print(model_history.history['val_accuracy'])
```

gives me
[0.9750000238418579, 0.9624999761581421, 0.956250011920929, 0.9624999761581421, 0.9624999761581421]
[0.9756097793579102]

How do I solve this problem without loosing out on the speed that is granted to me by the imagedatagenerator input?